# Windows Hello for Business - Hybrid Azure Joined Devices - Off LAN enrolment behaviour

Tags: entra-id, microsoft-intune

**Environment**
Windows 10 Professional devices, Hybrid Azure AD Joined (physical)
Server 2019 DCs
AD Connect 1.5.45
Key Trust setup
Endpoint Manager used to deploy WHfB
CRL distribution point published to internal and external web servers
Verified CA and CA+.crl files are accessible from LAN and non LAN connected Windows 10 endpoints

**Details**
When the WHfB wizard runs for the first time and the user is off the LAN, the PIN setup completes without issue.

However once the user signs out or locks the screen the PIN code does not work

"Your credentials could not be verified" is displayed. This is also taking into account the 30 min sync back to AD Connect.

However, once the user reverts to using their password to sign in and then activates the VPN AND then locks the workstation whilst still connected, the PIN code will work for the unlock.

Subsequent use of the PIN will also work when the VPN is not connected, including PIN change and reset.

LAN based devices have no issue at all and WHfB works as expected.

Can any advise what is the correct workflow when enrolling off LAN?

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is expected and by design:

> In the above deployment model (Hybrid Azure AD join authentication using a Key), a newly provisioned user will not be able to sign in using Windows Hello for Business until (a) Azure AD Connect successfully synchronizes the public key to the on-premises Active Directory and **(b) device has line of sight to the domain controller for the first time**.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/hello-how-it-works-authentication#hybrid-azure-ad-join-authentication-using-a-key

Comment: Thanks Noor, I will study that link you sent me. I understand the need to have line of of sight to the DCs now.

From what I can see, the TGT has be cached which appears to occur when the enrolled device locks the screen or logs out.

In both circumstances, the VPN must be in operation to achieve success.

Does this sound correct to you?

Comment: Yup, DC line of sight is required, you need to have VPN up and running at least for the first sign-in after the 30 minutes replica passes successfully.